# How to remove follow number after indent item in MS Word by using apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I use the following code to generate List idents in MS Word

```
CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();

cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.CHINESE_COUNTING);
cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("%1、"); 
cTLvl.addNewStart().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1)); 

CTInd cInd = cTLvl.addNewPPr().addNewInd();
cInd.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(960 + 120)); 
cInd.setHanging(BigInteger.valueOf(360));
```

after generated, it seems the indent with follow tab char by default
[image]

Is there any way to set Follow number with "nothing" by code ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work for me with pretty-old POI v3.17 and ooxml-schemas v1.4

pom:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

java:

```java
    CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
    cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(c));
    
    CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
    cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.DECIMAL);
    cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("%1.");
    cTLvl.addNewStart().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    cTLvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0)); 
    
    CTLevelSuffix sfx = CTLevelSuffix.Factory.newInstance();
    sfx.setVal(STLevelSuffix.NOTHING);
    cTLvl.setSuff(sfx);
    
    XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);
    XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();   
    BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);
    BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID); //set it to paragraph
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only way is to use xml when you create list. This is specification url. You need to see on **<w:suff w:val="space"/>**
[docx format](http://officeopenxml.com/WPnumberingLvl.php)

I use all these libs in maven, without last my sample didnt work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-full</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Code for create list:
First sample (I didnt use it and maybe you will have to change some operators and add null checks and etc, and maybe someone will found a way to replace xml string for enum value with CTLevelSuffixImpl):

```
CTNumbering ctNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.newInstance();
ctNumbering.getNumArray()[0].addNewLvlOverride().getLvl().setSuff(CTLevelSuffix.Factory.parse("<w:suff w:val=\\\"nothing\\\" />"));
XWPFNumbering numbering = document.getNumbering();
if (numbering == null)
    numbering = document.createNumbering();

CTAbstractNum ctAbstractNum = ctNumbering.getAbstractNumArray()[0];
ctAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
XWPFAbstractNum xwpfAbstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(ctAbstractNum);
BigInteger abstractNumId = numbering.addAbstractNum(xwpfAbstractNum);
BigInteger numId = numbering.addNum(abstractNumId);
```

Second sample (I use it and it work correctly):

```
CTNumbering ctNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse("<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
            + "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
            + "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:suff w:val=\"nothing\" /><w:start w:val=\"" + begin + "\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/>"
            + "<w:pPr> <w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr> \"<w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Times New Roman\" w:hAnsi=\"Times New Roman\"/>\"+\n" +
            "            \" <w:b> </w:b> <w:sz w:val=\"" + 14 * 2 + "\"/><w:szCs w:val=\"" + 14 * 2 + "\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl> </w:abstractNum>"); // paste in method argument your xml string with modification for your list
    XWPFNumbering numbering = document.getNumbering();
    if (numbering == null)
        numbering = document.createNumbering();
    CTAbstractNum ctAbstractNum = ctNumbering.getAbstractNumArray()[0];
    XWPFAbstractNum xwpfAbstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(ctAbstractNum);
    BigInteger abstractNumId = numbering.addAbstractNum(xwpfAbstractNum);
    BigInteger numId = numbering.addNum(abstractNumId);
```